# Starcraft 1 battlenet not working

Tags: wine, games

So I downloaded starcraft 1 from blizzard.com, because that's where I bought it, but when I go to play on battle.net, it tells me that battle.net was unable to identify my application version and that I may have a virus. Now I know I don't have a virus, so how can I make this work?

Comment: I just changed the options in wine to automatically capture the mouse in fullscreen windows (on) and allow the window manager to decorate the windows (on) allow the window manager to control the window (off) emulate a virtual desktop (off) and instead of not connecting to battle net it just shows a black screen with the white writing, anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=149

That might help.  Go down the page to the multiplayer how to.

Comment: Can you please add step-by-step instructions to this? Answers that are just a link to another website are usually just deleted here. This is explained more fully in the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion)s.